# Drawing a graph and extracting structure using R

Tags: r, graphml, yed

For a production planning software I need a specificly structured Excel input. Therefore, I was looking for a way to make it easy for non-tech people to generate such an input. To achieve that, I thought it might be easiest for users to draw their production network as graph and I could use the resulting graphml output to derive the necessary information and transform them to the format needed.

When looking for an appropriate and easy software I found **yEd**. To start with I generated a very simple network with 2 sites and 1 part being transfered and exported the graphml.
When I try to read the graphml in **R using igraph or casualeffect package** the names are lost and I get a lot of warnings.
For igraph the plot also looks incomplete.

What am I doing wrong? Should I use a different software or package? Any recommendations?

I hope my description is sufficient (that is my first post on stackoverflow)

Thank you a lot.

```
### 1st try
library(igraph)
net1<-read.graph("Graph test.graphml", format = "graphml")
plot(net1)
### 2nd try
library(causaleffect)
net2 <- parse.graphml("Graph test.graphml", use.names = TRUE)
plot(net2)
```

[Link for Graph Test on yEd](https://www.yworks.com/yed-live/?file=https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cociax/8d34e1f3c1451669e2976097e983d43f/raw/989aa5fa0bb39fb41d56fac79c5fec8273ee200e/Graph%20test)

[Link for graphml file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WxdAIgg5_z0l6h1Uyt4ta9ucYRStiPwC/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to extract nodes and edges from the graphml file without losing their names.